# Passing Stream to a Funtion and Leaving it Open

Tags: c#, stream

I am having trouble writing to stream.  I think i understand why, but im not really following how to get around the issue.  Please see example code below

The requirement that the caller of Writer in the example below manages the stream, not the Writer.

this is example code in the caller:

```
using (Stream stream1 = new MemoryStream())
using (Stream stream2 = new FileStream("ex.txt", FileMode.Create)) 
{
    //example 1:
    Writer writer1 = new Writer();
    writer1.WriteToStream(stream1); 

    //example 2:
    Writer writer2 = new Writer();
    writer2.WriteToStream(stream2);         
}
```

This is the `Writer` class:  its supposed to leave stream open after its done with it.

```
public class Writer
{
    public void WriteToStream(Stream destination)
    {
        Write(destination, "abc");
    }

    private void Write(Stream destination, string data)
    {
        Streamwriter sw = new StreamWriter(destination);
        sw.Write(data);
    }
}
```

in this setup, nothing shows up in `MemoryStream` or `"ex.txt"`.  I am guessing its because once you exit the `Write` method, `StreamWriter` is out of context, and stream goes with it before it gets a chance to be written to a file.
If I change the `Write` method to the example below, then i can get something to show up in the file, but the stream ends up closed, which goes against the requirement:

```
private void Write(Stream destination, string data)
{
    using(Streamwriter sw = new StreamWriter(destination))
    {   
        sw.Write(data);
    }
}
```

So, how do I write a string to a stream (Memory of File), without closing the stream in the process.  thank you

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_ (note the leaveOpen parameter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing Stream Flush.

Following will solve the issue:

```
private void Write(Stream destination, string data)
{
     var sw = new StreamWriter(destination);
     sw.Write(data);
     sw.Flush();
}
```

However, open streams are notorious.

Comment: Just FYI, this may cause some flakiness since the stream may or may not be closed before you finished using it elsewhere depending when garbage collection is run.

Comment: Agree - thats why I said "However, open streams are notorious." But this is what OP wants. Note the last line: "So, how do I write a string to a stream (Memory of File), without closing the stream in the process. thank you"

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is probably to use the [StreamWriter constructor that allows us to leave the underlying Stream open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamwriter.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_StreamWriter__ctor_System_IO_Stream_System_Text_Encoding_System_Int32_System_Boolean_) and set `leaveOpen`to true.

```
private void Write(Stream destination, string data)
{
    using (var sw = new StreamWriter(destination, Encoding.UTF8, 1024, leaveOpen: true))
    {
        sw.Write(data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Requiring a stream to be left open for an indeterminate amount of time after a Write is made is usually a poor design choice - especially in a multi-threaded environment for obvious reasons. Whilst your snippet is rather small and probably not indicative of your application context at large, it should be stressed that using `leaveOpen` has a very narrow use-case scenario.

Comment: @James Yes, you're right, the stream will need to be managed separately by the caller. The requirement from the op was that the stream be left open which the accepted answer does not necessarily do since it relies on garbage collect not happening at an inopportune time.